# Django: problem comparing strings in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm doing a simple `{% if %}` comparison but can't get the strings to match.

```
{% if request.user.username == empresa.vendedor|stringformat:"s" %}
```

I checked classes and:

`request.user.username` is `<class 'str'>`.

`empresa.vendedor|stringformat:"s"` is `<class 'str'>`.

I print a case and:

`request.user.username` is `Mariano`.

`empresa.vendedor|stringformat:"s"` is `Mariano`.

**In the model**

`empresa.vendedor` is a foreign key of `vendedores.nombre`

```
class empresa(models.Model):
    ..... other fields ......
    Vendedor = models.ForeignKey("Vendedores", help_text="Estatus del contenido", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['Nombre']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Nombre)

class Vendedores(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Nombre", blank=False, null=True)
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Apellido", blank=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nombre)
```

**Also tried**

```
{% if empresa.vendedor|stringformat:"s" in request.user.username %}
{% if request.user.username in empresa.vendedor|stringformat:"s" %}
{% if request.user.username == empresa.vendedor %}
{% if empresa.vendedor == request.user %}
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be the template filter causing the problem. Did you try just {% if request.user.username == empresa.vendedor %}?

Comment: @Whodini Yes I did, just forgot to include it. I updated the post with this intent too.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not `{% if empresa.vendedor == request.user %}`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman That doesn´t work either

Comment: Show your empresa model.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just updated the post

Comment: Try using Nombre i.e empresa.vendedor.nombre.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Have you tried</strike>

`{% if request.user.username == (empresa.vendedor|stringformat:"s") %}`?

Bitwise 'or' (`|`) has a lower precedence than `==`. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

OK, so Django's template language is *not* python, and I can't find a good reference for expressions in the template language. Sorry, nothing to see here, move on.

Comment: Just tryied it. I get a `TemplateSyntaxError could not parse some characters`.

Comment: Damn. Template expressions are not Python, and I don't have a way to test them where I am, and I can't find a good reference. if I do I'll update. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `with` directive?
I think the problem is that we can not use pipe directive inside conditions.

```
{% with empresa.vendedor|stringformat:"s" as data %}
  {% if request.user.username == data %}
  // do something
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

I had a similar problem once and I solved by this solution. 
I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a typo I was using `empresa.vendedor` and it should have been `Vendedor` due to a legacy database. Sorry and thanks to all.